# why the content in the cells are at the edges in the following output of a confusion matrix

Tags: machine-learning, confusion-matrix, graph-visualization

[image: why the content in the cells are at the edges]

the output of the confusion matrix is show above. 
the problem is the content of the code is placed at the end of the cell. how to resolve the issue.
how to format the following graph

the code is

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix


def make_confusion_matrix(cf,
                          group_names=None,
                          categories='auto',
                          count=True,
                          percent=True,
                          cbar=True,
                          xyticks=True,
                          xyplotlabels=True,
                          sum_stats=True,
                          figsize=None,
                          cmap='Blues',
                          title=None):
    '''
    This function will make a pretty plot of an sklearn Confusion Matrix cm using a Seaborn heatmap visualization.
    Arguments
    ---------
    cf:            confusion matrix to be passed in
    group_names:   List of strings that represent the labels row by row to be shown in each square.
    categories:    List of strings containing the categories to be displayed on the x,y axis. Default is 'auto'
    count:         If True, show the raw number in the confusion matrix. Default is True.
    normalize:     If True, show the proportions for each category. Default is True.
    cbar:          If True, show the color bar. The cbar values are based off the values in the confusion matrix.
                   Default is True.
    xyticks:       If True, show x and y ticks. Default is True.
    xyplotlabels:  If True, show 'True Label' and 'Predicted Label' on the figure. Default is True.
    sum_stats:     If True, display summary statistics below the figure. Default is True.
    figsize:       Tuple representing the figure size. Default will be the matplotlib rcParams value.
    cmap:          Colormap of the values displayed from matplotlib.pyplot.cm. Default is 'Blues'
                   See http://matplotlib.org/examples/color/colormaps_reference.html

    title:         Title for the heatmap. Default is None.
    '''


    # CODE TO GENERATE TEXT INSIDE EACH SQUARE
    blanks = ['' for i in range(cf.size)]

    if group_names and len(group_names)==cf.size:
        group_labels = ["{}\n".format(value) for value in group_names]
    else:
        group_labels = blanks

    if count:
        group_counts = ["{0:0.0f}\n".format(value) for value in cf.flatten()]
    else:
        group_counts = blanks

    if percent:
        group_percentages = ["{0:.2%}".format(value) for value in cf.flatten()/np.sum(cf)]
    else:
        group_percentages = blanks

    box_labels = [f"{v1}{v2}{v3}".strip() for v1, v2, v3 in zip(group_labels,group_counts,group_percentages)]
    box_labels = np.asarray(box_labels).reshape(cf.shape[0],cf.shape[1])


    # CODE TO GENERATE SUMMARY STATISTICS & TEXT FOR SUMMARY STATS
    if sum_stats:
        #Accuracy is sum of diagonal divided by total observations
        accuracy  = np.trace(cf) / float(np.sum(cf))

        #if it is a binary confusion matrix, show some more stats
        if len(cf)==2:
            #Metrics for Binary Confusion Matrices
            precision = cf[1,1] / sum(cf[:,1])
            recall    = cf[1,1] / sum(cf[1,:])
            f1_score  = 2*precision*recall / (precision + recall)
            stats_text = "\n\nAccuracy={:0.4f}\nPrecision={:0.4f}\nRecall={:0.4f}\nF1 Score={:0.4f}".format(
                accuracy,precision,recall,f1_score)
        else:
            stats_text = "\n\nAccuracy={:0.3f}".format(accuracy)
    else:
        stats_text = ""


    # SET FIGURE PARAMETERS ACCORDING TO OTHER ARGUMENTS
    if figsize==None:
        #Get default figure size if not set
        figsize = plt.rcParams.get('figure.figsize')

    if xyticks==False:
        #Do not show categories if xyticks is False
        categories=False


    # MAKE THE HEATMAP VISUALIZATION
    plt.figure(figsize=figsize)
    sns.heatmap(cf,annot=box_labels,fmt="",cmap=cmap,cbar=cbar,xticklabels=categories,yticklabels=categories)

    if xyplotlabels:
        plt.ylabel('True label')
        plt.xlabel('Predicted label' + stats_text)
    else:
        plt.xlabel(stats_text)

    if title:
        plt.title(title)
    plt.show()


labels = ["True_Neg","False_Pos","False_Neg","True_Pos"]
categories = ['Zero', 'One']
cm =  np.array([[54, 8],[0, 69]])#confusion_matrix(y_test,y_pred) [[545, 8],[0, 697]]
print(cm)
make_confusion_matrix(cm,group_names=labels,
                      categories=categories, 
                      )
```

This function will make a pretty plot of an sklearn Confusion Matrix cm using a Seaborn heatmap visualization.

Arguments
cf:            confusion matrix to be passed in
group_names:   List of strings that represent the labels row by row to be shown in each square.
categories:    List of strings containing the categories to be displayed on the x,y axis. Default is 'auto'

count:         If True, show the raw number in the confusion matrix. Default is True.

normalize:     If True, show the proportions for each category. Default is True.

cbar:          If True, show the color bar. The cbar values are based off the values in the confusion matrix.
                   Default is True.

xyticks:       If True, show x and y ticks. Default is True.

xyplotlabels:  If True, show 'True Label' and 'Predicted Label' on the figure. Default is True.

sum_stats:     If True, display summary statistics below the figure. Default is True.

figsize:       Tuple representing the figure size. Default will be the matplotlib rcParams value.

cmap:          Colormap of the values displayed from matplotlib.pyplot.cm. Default is 'Blues'
title:         Title for the heatmap. Default is None.

Comment: Please post the code *here*; see how to create a [mcve].

Comment: @desertnaut I have added it sir.